# Can someone help me with this coin change problem?

Tags: python, output

I have tried to change a lot of things but I always end up with no output. This project is supposed to output the minimum number of coins needed to pay the change to the customer.

When I run the program it does ask me for the input on **change owed** but I do not get any output and the program does not end.

```py
import cs50

dollars = float(input("Change Owed: "))
quarters = 0
nickels = 0
dimes = 0
pennies = 0
total_coins = 0


while (dollars<=0):
    dollars = float(input("Change Owed: "))
    continue

while (dollars > 0 ):
    if (dollars >= .25):
        dollars = dollars - .25
        quarters = quarters + 1
        total_coins = total_coins + 1

    if (dollars < .25 and dollars >= .10):
        dollars = dollars - .10
        dimes = dimes + 1
        total_coins = total_coins + 1

    if(dollars < .10 and dollars >= .5):
        dollars = dollars - .5
        nickels = nickels + 1
        total_coins = total_coins + 1

    if (dollars >= .1 and dollars < .5):
        dollars = dollars - .1
        pennies = pennies + 1
        total_coins = total_coins + 1


print ("Quarters: " + str(quarters))
print ("Dimes: " + str(dimes))
print ("Nickels: " + str(nickels))
print ("Pennies: " + str(pennies))
print (total_coins)
```

Comment: Can you write a more descriptive title? It would help people who are interested in the question find it more easily.

Comment: Check the value of a nickel and a penny. It should be 0.05 and 0.01 respectively.

Comment: Also, I'm not in front of an IDE to run this, but I don't think that you need the continue statement in the first loop.

Comment: Something can't be both greater than .5 and less than .1, so that statement can't ever execute.

Comment: Reconsider your use of floating point numbers. Your `0.1` is *explicitly used* as an example of why not to in [the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error).

Answer (score 1):

The bug I see that's most likely to make this loop go forever is that you specified the wrong values for nickels and pennies in some spots.  (The thing of looping on the dollar input is a little weird, but as far as I can tell that's a no-op unless the user specifically inputs a negative number -- if you wanted to check for invalid input you'd also want to check for inputs that aren't numbers at all!)

The fact that you have to repeat the same code for each coin, with the same values repeated each time, makes it very easy for this type of bug to creep in.  Here's a suggested approach that makes it so you only specify each coin once (making it very easy to check that the values are correct):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from enum import Enum
from typing import Dict


class Coin(Enum):
    QUARTERS = 0.25
    DIMES = 0.10
    NICKELS = 0.05
    PENNIES = 0.01


while True:
    try:
        dollars = float(input("Change Owed: "))
        assert dollars > 0
        break
    except AssertionError:
        print("I can only dispense non-negative amounts of change!")
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not even a number!")
num_coins: Dict[Coin, int] = defaultdict(int)

for coin in Coin:
    while dollars >= coin.value:
        num_coins[coin] += 1
        dollars -= coin.value

for coin in Coin:
    print(f"{coin.name.title()}: {num_coins[coin]}")
print(f"Total coins: {sum(num_coins.values())}")
```

A neat thing about this approach is that you can very easily add other kinds of coins (like `HALF_DOLLAR = 0.50`), and the code will just work with the addition of that one line to the enum!